# Put focus on JDialog

Tags: java, swing

I have class InfoDialog which extends JDialog class in Java. I show InfoDialog while I am establishing SSH connection ( 5 or 6 seconds ) with info text. How to put focus on InfoDialog that user cannot do anything else until InfoDialog runaway ?

Comment: you mean, lock the entire OS? I don't know if this is possible...

Comment: @bluefoot: System modal dialogs can do this, but not with pure java (thankfully, IMO)

Comment: @Nivas sorry. what I meant was: I don't know if this is possible with pure java :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can lock the entire OS, but you can definetly lock your application by setting it modal. See the [API of JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) or do something like this:

```
 JDialog info = new JDialog();
 info.setModal(true);
```

Comment: Java 6 adds more flexibility in making a dialog modal. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [Modality](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html):

Modality defines whether

> The new modality model enables the developer to scope, or limit, a dialog box's modality blocking.
>
> The following modality types are supported in Java SE 6:
>   **Modeless type** — A modeless dialog box
>   does not block any other window while
>   it is visible.
>   **Document-modal type** —
>   A document-modal dialog box blocks all
>   windows from the same document, except
>   windows from its child hierarchy. In
>   this context, a document is a
>   hierarchy of windows that share a
>   common ancestor, called the document
>   root, which is the closest ancestor
>   window without an owner.
>   **Application-modal type** — An
>   application-modal dialog box blocks
>   all windows from the same application,
>   except windows from its child
>   hierarchy. If several applets are
>   launched in a browser environment, the
>   browser is allowed to treat them
>   either as separate applications or as
>   a single application. This behavior is
>   implementation-dependent.
>   **Toolkit-modal type** — A toolkit-modal
>   dialog box blocks all windows that run
>   in the same toolkit, except windows
>   from its child hierarchy. If several
>   applets are launched, all of them run
>   with the same toolkit. Hence, a
>   toolkit-modal dialog box shown from an
>   applet may affect other applets and
>   all windows of the browser instance
>   that embeds the Java runtime
>   environment for this toolkit.

You can define modality while [creation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#Dialog%28java.awt.Window,%20java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29):

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(owner, Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
```

or [later](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType%28java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29):

```
dialog.setModalityType(type)
```

*There is one more level: *System Level Modality*, but this is not possible with just Java.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a [Progress Bar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for this.